# Is there a way to stop Xcode from inserting a closing parenthesis after typing an open paren followed by a space?

Tags: xcode, parentheses, code-completion

Nothing in any IDE anywhere infuriates me as much as this behaviour. I have searched for a way to stop it but cannot find it anywhere. I am constantly having to delete these idiotic auto-provided closing parentheses manually, to the extent that I now start doing it automatically as a reflex even when using well-designed IDEs.

Answer (score 7):

try this:
you can uncheck `Automatically insert closing braces("}")`
and/or `enable type over completions` and/or `automatically  balance brackets in Obj-c Method calls`
[image]

Comment: Interesting. "Enable type-over completions" turns out to be the key thing. Or, at least, it seems to work here. The other two I'd already tried. Had not occurred to me to try "type-over completions"; no obvious logical connection to me.